# Cannot find name 'console'. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The following snippet shows a typescript error at **LINE 4**:

```
import {Message} from './class/message';

function sendPayload(payload : Object) : any{
   let message = new Message(payload);
   console.log(message);   // LINE 4 
}
```

The error says:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'console'.
```

What could be the reason for this? Why it cannot find the object `console`?

Comment: Which browser you are trying in? In IE you'll not see console

Comment: @A.R I have not yet tried in a browser. Getting the typescript compiler error.

Comment: I experienced this problem when trying out node16, which is not yet an LTS.  Going back to node14 removed the problem.  Check the date on this comment!

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You will have to install the `@types/node` to get the node typings. You can achieve that by executing the below command:

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

If your `tsconfig.json` file has a `types` property, you should modify it or you'll have to explicitly import node.js types to use them:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["jsdom", ...],
    ...
  },
...
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do? It is still throwing the same warning?

Comment: Can you also try installing the typings as your local-dependency?. You can do that by executing, `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: It is working now. Could you please explain, as what exactly happened?

Comment: When you issue the above command, your `node.d.ts` file will get updated to have the Console definitions and the error/warnings will go away.

Comment: Still getting the error after installing `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.  Is there anything else I might have to change?

Comment: Can you try executing `npm cache clean` and try again please?

Comment: You may also need to explicitly include the node typedefs in your tsconfig.json like so:

`"types": ["node"]`

Comment: @pypmannetjies - The documentation doesn't match your claim.  Of course the documentation could be wrong!  The documentation says it uses types to **limit** which @types/xxxx modules are read in. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Comment: The error went away when I followed @pypmannetjies suggestion. But then I have typeRoots as well...  ‍♂️

Comment: If the error still persists after, try the oldest IT trick: restart the IDE

Answer (score 70):

Add "dom" in your lib section in compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

Example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "bin",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"    <------- Add this "dom" here
        ],
        "types": [
            "reflect-metadata"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You're both right. Use `npm install @types/node` if it's a Node/terminal app, or use `"lib": ["dom"]` if it's a browser app.

Comment: You may also need to explicitly include the node typedefs in your tsconfig.json like so:

`"types": ["node"]`

Comment: What's the best way to do it if it's a common module that should be able to run in browser *or* Node?

Comment: I have "dom" in the "lib" section of tsconfig.json but still getting the same error.  Any ideas?  This was working fine before.

Answer (score 16):

You can run `npm install @types/node -D`, and then you need to add `types:[ 'node']` into your `tsconfig.json` also.

`package.json`

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^15.0.3"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In my case, only the command `npm i @types/node -D` is enough, no need to do anything futher.

Answer (score 9):

just add ES6 and DOM in your tsconfig.json file

```js
"lib": ["ES6", "DOM"]
```

Comment: Why do you need `DOM`? Where is that documented?

Comment: `DOM` inadvertently contains definitions for `console`, but what you really want is `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.

Comment: @simbabque because it contains definitions for console

Answer (score 3):

you can also use the same values as in @tBlabs answer from command line, and you don't need to install anything beside typescript:

```
tsc test.ts --lib esnext,dom
```

you separate values with comma and you don't need esnext for console.log to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in node terminal. Adding `node` to the `types` field of `tsconfig.json` solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `typescript` so here are the steps you need to do.

1. Install global `tsc` using

```
npm I typescript --global
```

2. call `tsc --init` if you don't have a `tsconfig.json` already in your folder
3. If you have a `tsconfig.json` in the `lib` consider including `DOM` like this

```
 "lib": ["DOM" ...],
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this Issue When i Started to use .env File

and

when i begin to Import the date from .env File

and

Also to Note that , the error is only in the Files where we Import the Things from .env

In My case i just added in tsConfig

```
"types": ["node"],
```

This Solved my issue  Orelse if you want you can also Imstall @types/node

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

hope this helpes
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Confirm that you don't import `console` from anything. like:

`import { console } from 'console'; // Confirm you haven't a statement like this.`